# Putty command from Perl

Tags: perl, putty

I am trying to run a couple of commands in putty from perl. Right now my code gets me into putty but I am unsure of how to execute commands from there.

```
my $PUTTY = 'C:\Users\Desktop\putty.exe';
my $dacPutty = "$PUTTY, -ssh username@server - l username -pw password";
system ($dacPutty);

system (ls);
```

Comment: So you want to control a putty ash session from within Perl?

Comment: Install cygwin and use its `ssh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in Perl it's better to use a Perl module, where one exists, than to shell out.

Using a module is more portable, and often gives you more control. `system` introduces many opportunities for security bugs, so it's good to avoid it where possible.

In this case, use Net::SSH::Perl http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.38/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm

Once installed:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("host1");
$ssh->login("user1", "pass1");

$ssh->cmd("cd /some/dir");
$ssh->cmd("foo");
```

For reliability, you should actually check the result of each cmd:

```
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("cd /some/dir");
unless ($exit == 0) {
     // Handle failed cd
}
```

The document notes that with SSH-1, each `cmd` reconnects, so the above would not work -- you would `cd` in one shell, then `foo` in a completely new shell. If you have to use SSH-1, then you'd need to do:

```
$ssh->cmd("cd /some/dir; foo");
```

(And you can use a similar trick even if you're making a `system` call to plink)

Comment: The you-get-a-new-session-for-every-command thing also happens with SSH-2 even if the connection is reused.

Answer (score 3):

use plink instead. ( http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html )
plink is in the same directory as putty.

Comment: The OP has a followup question, but doesn't have enough rep yet to comment on your answer: *"I've successfully started using plink, however I am still unsure of how to change directory within plink directly from my code" -cbrunner9*